# Moment Timezone - Detect if given time is ambiguous

Tags: momentjs

Is there a way to check if an epoch is ambiguous or not in momentjs?

In `America/Chicago` zone,  `2011-11-06 00:00` is not ambiguous but `2011-11-06 01:00` can be either Central Daylight Time (*CDT*) or Savings Time (*CST*).

Comment: What do you mean with _ambiguous_? For a given moment object you can use [`isDST()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/) to knwon if it is in daylight saving time. Anyway I fear that your question is a bit unclear and you have to edit to explain further what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks @VincenzoC, made the edits, `isDST()` would tell me if the date falls within DST range, not the time.

Comment: how would you define ambiguous ? and what exactly you are trying to achieve by finding that, could you please explain your use case in more detailed manner

Comment: Background on parsing ambiguity [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-ambiguous-inputs/). If a user types a datetime that is falling in more than 1  zone for the same region then we would ask them which time they meant. Based on their choice (in this case CST/CDT) we need to pass the appropriate offset to momentjs to get the correct time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this will work:

```
function hasAmbiguousWallTime(m) {
    var t = [60, -60, 30, -30];
    var a = t.map(function(x) { return moment(m).add(x, 'm').format('HH:mm'); });
    return a.indexOf(m.format('HH:mm')) > -1;
}
```

Examples:

```
hasAmbiguousWallTime(moment.tz("2011-11-06 01:00", "America/Chicago")) // true
hasAmbiguousWallTime(moment.tz("2011-11-06 00:00", "America/Chicago")) // false
```

Note that this might fail for transitions that are not either 30 or 60 minutes change in offset, which have occurred historically.  A better implementation would test the known transition points in the moment-timezone data, or scan for them against a locally derived moment.  That said, the above is sufficient for most modern usage.

Comment: Would you be willing to expand on the suggestion of (what I believe you to be saying) scanning for known transition points in against a locally derived moment?  I'm faced with the task of prompting the user to clarify ambiguously entered local times (preferably by letting them pick from a list of offset names if possible), and I'll gratefully receive all help I can get on this.