# Formatting 0 in momentjs transforms to 1

Tags: javascript, momentjs

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajMEyo?editors=0012

I pass in 0 like `moment(0).format('HH:mm a')` and this transforms to *"01:00 am"*. I linked a codepen just incase.

The actual momentjs object looks like 

`Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: 0, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}`

But when I try to format it, to display, it transforms it to `01:00 am`. I'm passing in 0. As in, 0 seconds have elapsed therefore, i'm expecting `00:00:00` as the start of the day. But It's being transformed at some point and I don't see mention of this in the docs.

Comment: Hi! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set 00:00:00 using moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762383/how-to-set-000000-using-moment-js)

Comment: Sounds like a UTC/local timezone thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) of what you are actually calling

> #### Unix Timestamp (milliseconds)
>
> Similar to new Date(Number), you can create a moment by passing an integer value representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC).

```
moment(0).toString()
```

Output

```
Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500
```

---

If you want the beginning of todays date you should use [startOf](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)

> #### Start of Time
>
> Mutates the original moment by setting it to the start of a unit of time.

```
moment().startOf('date').toString()
```

Output

```
Mon Aug 13 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400
```

Answer (score 1):

This could have something to do with the timezone you are in. The `01:00 am` makes it looks like you are in a timezone which UTC+1

With `moment().utcOffset()` you can determine your offset to UTC. Perhaps this is 1 hour. You can use `moment().local()` to get your times in local timezone.

Comment: So `moment().local()` gives me a momentjs obejct. How can i use this for a conditional statement. Say; `if (moment().local() === '+1 of any timezone') doSomething()`

Comment: Okay, i think this answers my question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682560/moment-timezone-detect-if-given-time-is-ambiguous I will try this :)